# Query a service behind domain authentication from WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, active-directory

Is it even possible for WP7 app to connect to service which is stored behind domain authentication?

I found [Windows Domain Authentication on Windows Phone 7](http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2011/03/02/Windows-Domain-Authentication-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) article but it's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve.